# Connecting an Existing Site and Existing Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

I have this same question from over three years ago:

[Connecting an existing group to and existing site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269893/connecting-an-existing-group-to-and-existing-site-collection/303212#303212)

> It pretty easy to connect an O365 group to an existing SharePoint site
> collection through settings => Connect to new Office 365 Group.
>
> But how can we connect an existing site collection to an existing O365
> Group? Powershell is preferred but I would be interested to know if
> this is possible through the browser.

Has anything changed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is still the case. When you create a Microsoft 365 group, it comes with a connected SharePoint site. I think this is why you can't connect an existing M365 group to a SharePoint site but you can connect a SharePoint site to a new M365 group via this process. More information can be found here:

[Connect to a Microsoft 365 group](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same answer. You cannot connect an existing site collection to an existing O365 Group.